# CS50 appliance 2014 not working after trying to install updates

Tags: cs50

I recently tried to **update the software of CS50 2014 appliance virtual machine**. After updates , it asked for restart. I confirmed to restart.

But now, it is only **showing a black window** similar to a command prompt window where i am prompted to enter my username and password.

Even after entering details, **desktop does not appear**. Rather it remains like a command prompt window. I can't reach the desktop screen.

I have many of my important programs in that virtual machine.Can someone help me to get my files??

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that the updates were completely installed and were not interrupted? Because this problem generally occurs when an interruption occurs.You could try updating the appliance again. I recently did an update of the CS50 2014 appliance and and it took a while for whole of the updates to be installed.It was interrupted once and I could also access only a command prompt like screen.But I ran the updates once again and after that,it worked perfectly fine.

Comment: Yeah.It asked me for restart.Finw, i will try to update again.